# Designer preview is invisible in Visual Studio 2013 and Blend 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, blend, win-universal-app

[image: VS 2013 example]

This happens in both VS and Blend 2013, with the WP and Windows designer (no appbar on this page and application title on other default pages, no matter what controll I add to the page, it's selectable but not visible on either app).

Can't find answers on Google or SO as there are no errors as with similar situations.

If anyone has encountered the same problem and managed to fix it, I would appreciate it.

*PS: PC was recently formatted, only added to VS Resharper and the MVVMLight extension, if it helps.*

Comment: Without seeing what markup is generating a blank preview, it's pretty hard to say much here, other than that may be exactly what you're supposed to be seeing.

Comment: Tried on another desktop, same solution looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/0fef9LC.png). A blank page on WP or Win8 is not transparent like the one in the picture, it has a black background (not markup related).

Comment: Not to belabor the point but `<Page Background="Transparent">` produces this behavior. However, I imagine that's not the markup we're looking at. Are you seeing any errors in your Output tab with Show output from General selected?

Comment: Nope, like the post said, no errors. Even with that markup, on the screenshot you can see that there is a taskbar (although not the whole code) with 2 buttons with the respective icons. When deployed the app runs fine and shows everything.

Comment: Add button to the page. It looks that you have no controls that can display something without data from codebehind.

Comment: The first screenshot has an appbar/commandbar set through xaml, no need for codebehind. Still, the whole screen is transparent.